# Mathematica is taking too much time in solving my problem

Tags: equation-solving

My problem is

```
Solve[{((k - 3.05)^2) + ((l - 3.96)^2) == 25, 
  c^2 + d^2 == X1^2, ((e - g)^2) + ((f - h)^2) == 
   X2^2, ((e - c)^2) + ((f - d)^2) == 
   X3^2, ((k - c)^2) + ((l - d)^2) == 
   X4^2, ((k - e)^2) + ((l - f)^2) == 
   X5^2, ((k - m)^2) + ((l - n)^2) == 
   X6^2, ((k - i)^2) + ((l - j)^2) == 
   X7^2, ((i - m)^2) + ((j - n)^2) == 
   X8^2, ((i - g)^2) + ((j - h)^2) == 
   X9^2, ((m - s)^2) + ((n - t)^2) == 
   X10^2, ((s - g)^2) + ((t - h)^2) == X11^2, 
  s^2 + t^2 == X12^2, ((s - q)^2) + ((t - r)^2) == 
   X13^2, ((q - o)^2) + ((r - p)^2) == 
   X14^2, ((k - q)^2) + ((l - r)^2) == 
   X15^2, ((k - o)^2) + ((l - p)^2) == X16^2, o^2 + p^2 == X17^2, 
  g^2 + h^2 == 
   X18^2, (X4/X3) == (X6/X7) == (X14/X16) == (X12/X18), (X4/
     X5) == (X6/X8) == (X14/X15) == (X12/X11), (X3/X5) == (X7/
     X8) == (X16/X15) == (X18/X11)}, {c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m,
   n, o, p, q, r, s, t, X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9, X10, X11, 
  X12, X13, X14, X15, X16, X17, X18}]
```

Comment: Some geometrical background on this circles' intersection problem would be useful.

Comment: `Length[system]` 22
`Length[vars]` 36 Are you sure it's solvable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This numerical approach seems to work:

```
Norm2[x_] := x.x;
ConvertEquationsToLeastSquares[eqns : {__Equal}] := 
  Norm2@Flatten[eqns //. {
      Equal[x_, y_, rest___] -> {Subtract[x, y], Equal[y, rest]},
      True -> Nothing
      }];

FindMinimum[
 ConvertEquationsToLeastSquares@{((k - 3.05)^2) + ((l - 3.96)^2) == 
    25, c^2 + d^2 == X1^2, ((e - g)^2) + ((f - h)^2) == 
    X2^2, ((e - c)^2) + ((f - d)^2) == 
    X3^2, ((k - c)^2) + ((l - d)^2) == 
    X4^2, ((k - e)^2) + ((l - f)^2) == 
    X5^2, ((k - m)^2) + ((l - n)^2) == 
    X6^2, ((k - i)^2) + ((l - j)^2) == 
    X7^2, ((i - m)^2) + ((j - n)^2) == 
    X8^2, ((i - g)^2) + ((j - h)^2) == 
    X9^2, ((m - s)^2) + ((n - t)^2) == 
    X10^2, ((s - g)^2) + ((t - h)^2) == X11^2, 
   s^2 + t^2 == X12^2, ((s - q)^2) + ((t - r)^2) == 
    X13^2, ((q - o)^2) + ((r - p)^2) == 
    X14^2, ((k - q)^2) + ((l - r)^2) == 
    X15^2, ((k - o)^2) + ((l - p)^2) == X16^2, o^2 + p^2 == X17^2, 
   g^2 + h^2 == 
    X18^2, (X4/X3) == (X6/X7) == (X14/X16) == (X12/X18), (X4/
      X5) == (X6/X8) == (X14/X15) == (X12/X11), (X3/X5) == (X7/
      X8) == (X16/X15) == (X18/X11)}
 , {c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, X1, X2, X3, 
  X4, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9, X10, X11, X12, X13, X14, X15, X16, X17, 
  X18}, MaxIterations -> 1000
 ]
```

> {1.56647*10^-17, {c -> 0.0933043, d -> 0.607492, e -> 0.78842, 
>     f -> -0.146715, g -> 0.312364, h -> 0.370249, i -> 0.582798, 
>     j -> -0.0358372, k -> 0.195646, l -> -0.145199, m -> 0.384374, 
>     n -> 0.0853502, o -> 0.549876, p -> 0.585871, q -> 0.644724, 
>     r -> -0.00824668, s -> 0.0327058, t -> 0.357263, X1 -> 0.614616, 
>     X2 -> -0.702766, X3 -> 1.02568, X4 -> 0.759618, X5 -> 0.592776, 
>     X6 -> 0.297945, X7 -> 0.402302, X8 -> 0.232505, X9 -> -0.487894, 
>     X10 -> -0.44453, X11 -> 0.27996, X12 -> 0.358757, X13 -> -0.712856, 
>     X14 -> 0.601641, X15 -> 0.469497, X16 -> 0.812368, X17 -> 0.803497, 
>     X18 -> 0.484413}}

Comment: Man you are a lifesaver, thanks. Though i want to ask you that what is this first term in solution is indicated. I am new to mathematica.

Comment: The first term is the remaining 'energy' of the least squares problem I set up for FindMinimum. It is `ConvertEquationsToLeastSquares@{...}` evaluated for the variable values given next.

Comment: Hey, the syntax that you have given is providing me solution for just one value of k and l , but the first equation that i have given is a equation of circle so it should give me value of all the variable so that all the vaues of k and l of that circle can be found, i think i should use function 'for all' for say k and put a range for max. and min. value of k, but i don't know the syntax for that, can you help me for same?